# Physical reason for the diamagnetic behaviour of closed-shell atoms & the free electron gas

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics

We know that atoms with closed shell structure i.e., with $L=S=J=0$, exhibit purely diamagnetic behaviour, known as the **Larmor diamagnetism**. Using the quantum theory, I can calculate the magnetization and show that the susceptibility is negative. All of this is fine. But what is going on underneath the equations? What is happening to the closed-shell atoms in a magnetic field that causes them to behave diamagnetically (i.e., repelled by a magnetic field)? The trouble is that, unlike paramagnetism, the diamagnetic effect in quantum mechanics, cannot be picturized in terms of the alignment of spins in the presence of an external magnetic field.

**N.B.** I am not interested in the classical explanation of the diamagnetic effect if it has nothing to do with the quantum descriptions and quantum mechanical derivation of Larmor diamagnetism.

---

Similarly, I understand the Landau levels occur in a free electron gas subjected to a uniform external magnetic field. But based on that, how can we understand the occurrence of **Landau diamagnetism**, in physical terms? So what I need is a physical interpretation of underlying equations.

Comment: Don’t you rather mean [Langevin diamagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism#Theory) for closed atomic shells?

Comment: Ashcroft and Mermin's book uses the term "Larmor diamagnetism".

Comment: These are at least two separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

In closed-shell atoms with L=S=J=0, the diamagnetic behavior arises from the response of orbital electrons to an external magnetic field. According to quantum mechanics, when an external magnetic field is applied, the electrons experience a change in their orbital motion, generating a circulating current loop. This induced current loop, in turn, produces a magnetic moment opposing the external field, resulting in diamagnetism.

For closed-shell atoms, the filled electron shells exhibit a cancellation of individual magnetic moments due to pairing of spins, leading to a net diamagnetic response. The quantum mechanical description involves the subtle interplay of electron motion and magnetic interactions, capturing the essence of diamagnetic behavior without invoking classical explanations.

Regarding Landau diamagnetism, in a uniform magnetic field, electrons in a material experience quantized energy levels known as Landau levels. The physical interpretation lies in the quantization of electron motion into discrete orbits perpendicular to the magnetic field. As the magnetic field increases, electrons occupy higher Landau levels, contributing to a decrease in the overall magnetic susceptibility of the material. This reduction in susceptibility is a manifestation of Landau diamagnetism, rooted in the quantum nature of electron motion in magnetic fields.

Comment: Unfortunately, your explanation of Larmor diamagnetism is not quantum mechanical and has nothing to do with the quantitative derivation from perturbation theory.